# Background converted from white to grey when read in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have this image:
[image]
As can be seen the background is white, and when viewed in the finder/explorer it shows the background as white or very light grey.

But when I read this image into matlab using the basic command: `imread(img_name);`

It is read in like this:

[image]

Why is it changing the colour of the background?

I thought maybe its indexed and tried converting it back to grey with the command:

```
[map, im] = imread(img_name);
new = in2gray(im, map);
```

But that didn't work as well as I get an error stating that `map` is not a valid colourmap

**edit**
`imfinfo` output added:

```
              Filename: 'U:\IAM_manual\010.png'
           FileModDate: '27-Jun-2015 17:32:03'
              FileSize: 1843331
                Format: 'png'
         FormatVersion: []
                 Width: 2078
                Height: 2056
              BitDepth: 8
             ColorType: 'indexed'
       FormatSignature: [137 80 78 71 13 10 26 10]
              Colormap: [256x3 double]
             Histogram: []
         InterlaceType: 'none'
          Transparency: 'none'
SimpleTransparencyData: []
       BackgroundColor: []
       RenderingIntent: 'perceptual'
        Chromaticities: [0.3127 0.3290 0.6400 0.3300 0.3000 0.6000 0.1500 0.0600]
                 Gamma: 0.4545
           XResolution: 3779
           YResolution: 3779
        ResolutionUnit: 'meter'
               XOffset: []
               YOffset: []
            OffsetUnit: []
       SignificantBits: []
          ImageModTime: []
                 Title: []
                Author: []
           Description: []
             Copyright: []
          CreationTime: []
              Software: 'paint.net 4.0.5'
            Disclaimer: []
               Warning: []
                Source: []
               Comment: []
             OtherText: []
```

Comment: what is the size and type of `im`? Do you use `imshow` or `imagesc`?

Comment: @NKN it's a png file before being read in. Matlab reads it in as ``uint8``.  I am using ``imshow``

Comment: what is the output of `imfinfo('Your image name')`? This might be due to an alpha channel not being read or something like that.

Comment: @Benoit_11 ``imfinfo`` added to original post

Comment: what happens when you do `imshow(img, [] );`?

Comment: BTW, you flipped the arguments for `imread` with colormap: `[im map]=imread(img_name);` and `imshow( im, map );`

Comment: @Shai Thank you, you are correct in both your comments. The arguments were flipped, my mistake there. Flipping them back and then using ``ind2gray`` worked. Also ``imshow(img, [])`` also worked. What does ``imshow(img, [])`` mean?

Comment: @FarazKhan the empty second argument `[]` tells `imshow` to scale the intensities of the image to span the entire [0..1] range for display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like your image is indeed an indexed one, you should read the image and the colormap:

```
[img map] = imread( img_name ); %// note that img is BEFORE map output
imshow( img, map );
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: I've created a MATLAB chat room for us to discuss things MATLAB related, or for discussions that span beyond the limitations of a single comment.  Visit us when you have time! - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab